# How can you handle class name changes in laravel queues?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

When I queue up a laravel mailable to execute 15 minutes later like so:

```
Mail::to($user)->later(now()->addMinutes(15), new EmailConfirm($user));
```

Laravel will store the `EmailConfrim` class in the `payload` column in the `jobs` table.

If I do a release which changes the class name `EmailConfirm` to `ConfirmEmail` I will get the following error when the code executes 15 minutes later:

```
prod.ERROR: Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable::handle(): The script 
tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object.
Please ensure that the class definition 
"App\Mail\Mailables\EmailConfrim" of the object you are trying to
operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an 
autoloader to load the class definition
```

This error is telling me that the class defined in the payload no longer exists.

A solution I've been toying with is to add an `app_version_number` to the laravel generated `jobs` table. I would then not let my laravel workers die until all the jobs are executed for that version before running:

`php artisan queue:restart`.

This will take me a bit of time to reliably code this as it will be specific to our prod environment.  How could I go about managing this problem in a more eloquent way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd temporarily leave *both* classes in the codebase, deploy that, and then 15 minutes (or whatever the maximum amount of time a job lingers around) later push the *removal* of the old one.

Comment: Ahhh ok... Not super happy but I agree that this is the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314953/2191572 **BUT** I would recommend maintaining the `EmailConfirm` via extension to avoid double-duty maintenance while your queue catches up:

```
class EmailConfirm extends ConfirmEmail
{
    // This is just a shell/alias/wrapper/whatever for the real class
}

class ConfirmEmail
{
    function __construct( $param )
    {
        // Maintain this class
    }
}
```

15 minutes isn't so bad in terms of wait time but what if your queue doesn't catch up for several days and you need to change `ConfirmEmail` multiple times?

Comment: Ah ok, Yea. This will ensure that the same code is being run on both classes to stop human error e.g. I copy paste the class but then change something in the original class.

Comment: Good call on the inheritance.

Comment: Why override constructor just to call parent's one?

Comment: @Styx I wanted to make it verbose enough for OP to understand but I've figured out a better way to represent my thoughts. Thanks!